# Definition of Functional Interface in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, functional-interface

The definition of a functional Interface in Java 8 says:

> A functional interface is defined as any interface that has **exactly**
>   **one explicitly** declared abstract method. (The qualification is
>   necessary because an interface may have non-abstract default methods.)
>   This is why functional interfaces used to be called Single Abstract
>   **Method (SAM)** interfaces, a term that is still sometimes seen.

So how come we have this:

```
List<Double> temperature = 
   new ArrayList<Double>(Arrays.asList(new Double[] { 20.0, 22.0, 22.5 }));
temperature.sort((a, b) -> a > b ? -1 : 1);
```

As the `sort` method in `List` is:

```
default void sort(Comparator<? super E> c) {
        Object[] a = this.toArray();
        Arrays.sort(a, (Comparator) c);
        ListIterator<E> i = this.listIterator();
        for (Object e : a) {
            i.next();
            i.set((E) e);
        }
    }
```

And the lambda expression says:

> Lambda Expression should be assignable to a Functional Interface

The `Comparator` interface has two abstract methods which are `compare` and `equals` and is annotated with `@FunctionalInterface`. Does not this violate the definition of a functional interface having only one abstract method?

Comment: Every class in Java inherits from `Object` and has the implicit methods `Object::toString`, `Object::equals`, `Object::hashCode`. Therefore `Comparator<T>` is an interface with a SAM which overrides the implicit method.

Comment: Where did you get that definition?

Comment: There are a lot of blogs where I read the definition which I shared above. And as per the guidelines of stackoverflow I cannot share the link to other blogs..

Comment: Don’t base your knowledge on Blogs. There is [enough](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) [official](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) [material](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8) to study. You may use 3rd party tutorials and blogs, but if they cause confusion, verify with the official sources.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is true that the [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface has 2 abstract methods. But one of them is `equals`, which overrides the `equals` method defined in the `Object` class, and this method doesn't count.

From [`@FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html):

> If an interface declares an abstract method overriding one of the public methods of `java.lang.Object`, that also does *not* count toward the interface's abstract method count since any implementation of the interface will have an implementation from `java.lang.Object` or elsewhere.

As such, this makes the `Comparator` interface a functional interface where the functional method is [`compare(o1, o2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-).

The lambda expression `(a, b) -> a > b ? -1 : 1` complies with that contract: it declares 2 parameters and return an `int`.

Comment: And if we are at it, it should be emphasized that this definition, unlike claimed in the question’s quote, does not require the abstract method to be declared explicitly.

Comment: And it should be mentioned that, while this lambda expression complies with the *shape* of the function and hence is accepted by the compiler, it is violating the *contract* of the `Comparator` interface and can cause an arbitrary mess at runtime…

Comment: Yes, in this case `Comparator.reverseOrder()` would be a better choice.