# Where is get() in Supplier interface implemented?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-interface

I have this piece of code

```
public <T> someMethod(Supplier<T> supplier) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(supplier);
        SupplierThrowsException<T, Throwable> supplierThrowsException = supplier::get;
        return withThrowable(supplierThrowsException);
}
```

I am calling it like this

```
obj.someMethod(() -> myMethod(message))
```

I am 100% sure that the class of the object returned by `myMethod()` does not implement Supplier interface. So where is the implementation of `get()`.

I went through the Javadoc, I didn't get anything. I would like to understand what's going on here.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417262/java-8-supplier-consumer-explanation-for-the-layperson) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050679/purpose-of-functional-interfaces-in-java8) but it doesn't clear my doubt. Let me know if I am missing anything here.

Comment: You need to understand how lambda expressions work (and *functional* interfaces). It's the lambda expression `() -> myMethod(message)` that implements `Supplier.get`

Comment: Is there any Interface for lambdas in java? Could you point out some docs, articles or posts that would explain this?

Comment: Here's a good place to start: [Why do I need a functional Interface to work with lambdas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010594/why-do-i-need-a-functional-interface-to-work-with-lambdas)

Comment: @raviiii1 try implementing the anonymous class representation of the lambda and things would be much clearer to understand and correlate them.

Comment: @ernest_k, if the expression () -> `myMethod(message)` implements Supplier.get, then how does it return SupplierThrowsException<T, Throwable> in the example?

Comment: @raviiii1 It returns the result of calling `withThrowable(supplierThrowsException)`, and that is NOT `SupplierThrowsException<T, Throwable>`. I'd guess that the return type of `withThrowable` is `T` (the same `T` as returned by `supplier`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am 100% sure that the class of the object returned by `myMethod()` does not implement `Supplier` interface.

Sure, but the expression `() -> myMethod(message)` does.

Please, read [15.27.4. Run-Time Evaluation of Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.4).

> At run time, evaluation of a lambda expression **is similar to evaluation of a class instance creation expression**, insofar as normal completion produces a reference to an object. Evaluation of a lambda expression is distinct from execution of the lambda body.
>
> Either **a new instance of a class with the properties below is allocated and initialized, or an existing instance of a class with the properties below is referenced**.
>
> **The value of a lambda expression is a reference to an instance of a class** with the following properties:
>
> - **The class implements the targeted functional interface type** and, if the target type is an intersection type, every other interface type mentioned in the intersection.

In short, the lambda expression `() -> myMethod(message)` will be resolved to an instance of `Supplier`.

> Where is the implementation of `get`()?

You've provided it within the lambda body.

```
() -> myMethod(message)
```

(it's a statement expression, a shorter form to construct a lambda body)

```
() -> {
    return myMethod();
}
```

(it's a value-compatible block, a more expanded version where many statements may be declared)

Answer (score 3):

In this call:

```
obj.someMethod(() -> myMethod(message))
```

you are implementing the `Supplier` interface using a lambda expression - `() -> myMethod(message)`.

It is as if (I say "as if" because this is not what actually happens under the hood. [Here](https://www.infoq.com/articles/Java-8-Lambdas-A-Peek-Under-the-Hood) is what happens under the hood) you have created an inner class implementing `Supplier` like this:

```
static class MyInnerClass implements Supplier<SomeClass> {
    public SomeClass get() {
        return myMethod(message);
    }
}
```

And then passed `new MyInnerClass()` to `someMethod`.

Comment: How `static` for overidden method `get()`?

Answer (score 1):

I think this document may shed some light on your question:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#target-typing

> To determine the type of a lambda expression, the Java compiler uses the target type of the context or situation in which the lambda expression was found. It follows that you can only use lambda expressions in situations in which the Java compiler can determine a target type:
>
> Variable declarations
>
> Assignments
>
> Return statements
>
> Array initializers
>
> Method or constructor arguments
>
> Lambda expression bodies
>
> Conditional expressions, ?:
>
> Cast expressions

Comment: The link that you shared is really helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

`Supplier` is a functional interface and contains following single abstract method:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Supplier<T> {

    /**
     * Gets a result.
     *
     * @return a result
     */
    T get();
}
```

Now, you have provided `definition` of `get` method along with `instantiation` with following invocation:

```
obj.someMethod(() -> myMethod(message))
```

Above line gets translated as follows:

```
obj.someMethod(new Supplier() {

@Override
public T get() 
{ 
  return myMethod(message);
}

});
```